# How can I get all the values from a key from Firebase Realtime DB?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, androidx

I want to get all the values from a key inside a category key.

I'm using AndroidX, Gradle 5.1.1 and I am working with this structure:

```
db-name
    category1
        unique_random_id: value
        unique_random_id2: value_value
    category2
        unique_random_id: value
        unique_random_id2: value_value
```

```java
    ListView lv;
    FirebaseDatabase fb;
    DatabaseReference dr;

    ArrayList<Article> list;
    ArrayAdapter<Article> adapter;
    Article article;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.articlelist);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle gotExtras = intent.getExtras();

        final TextView articleCatShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.articleCatShow);
        articleTopCat.setText(gotExtras.getString("cat"));

        article = new Article();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dr = fb.getReference(gotExtras.getString("cat"));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Article>(this, R.layout.article_each, R.id.articleTxt, list);

        dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    adapter.add(ds.getValue(Article.class));
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
}
```

I expected that the listview had the data.

I also get this error when I run the app and press the button that will Intent with Extras `Can't convert an object of type java.lang.String to type <my-hidden-package-name>`

Comment: what is your `cat` value in bundle which you are passing? and do not set adapter in for loop

Comment: @Priyankagb I'm sending the category name

Comment: is it string or anything else?

Comment: @Priyankagb It's a string

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
       dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    adapter.add(ds.getValue(Article.class));
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
```

into this:

```
       dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    adapter.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Article.class));
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
```

Removing the `for` loop since when you iterate you retrieve values of type `String` and not the type of your package.

Comment: Good catch Peter. I read the error message wrong, so thought it was casting an object to a string instead of vice versa.

Comment: I did what you said, now on my ListView, I get a single item saying `<my-private-package-name>@91e228a`

Comment: yes because you should do `Article article = ds.getValue(Article.class); String name = article.getName(); adapter.add(name);` @ItsBenny_

Comment: @ItsBenny_ `@91e228a` this is the hashcode of your object `Article` which means you are retrieving it, but you should access the instance variables in your class, so if you have lets say `setName` and `getName` then do as I told you. If your variables are publish then just do `article.name` (not the name of the instance variable is `name` here.)

Comment: @PeterHaddad `adapter.add(name)` raises an error `in ArrayAdapter cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)` Name: `String name = article.getArticle();`

Comment: change this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Article>(this, R.layout.article_each, R.id.articleTxt, list);` to this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.article_each, R.id.articleTxt, list);` @ItsBenny_

Comment: `Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(packagename, int, int, java.util.ArrayList<packagename.Articlei>)'` @PeterHaddad

Comment: @ItsBenny_ you are not using the arraylist that you declared...its empty.. do the following: `String name = article.getName();
                                    list.add(name);
                                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` add the following code inside `addValueEventListener`

Comment: also change both `ArrayList<Article> list;
    ArrayAdapter<Article> adapter;` to    `ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;`

Comment: 'adapter' highlights with red underline `Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(packagename, int, int, java.util.ArrayList<packagename.Article>)'`

Edit: Fixed it by changing `this` to `<activityJavaFileName>.this`

Comment: Seems like it works.
This is my structure of Firebase
`db-name:
 category:
  articleSpecifiedID: Value
  articleUniqueRandomID: Value
  articelUniqueRandomID: Value
`
and my `Article.java` has the `articleSpecifiedID` (which is for testing and the id is `article`) so its getting the specified id. Another problem is its not looping and getting all the values. @PeterHaddad

Comment: @ItsBenny_ no it is retrieving everything, but the problem is that the `listview` can only have one textview if you want more `views` in it you need to create a custom listview as specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894563/how-to-populate-multiple-data-in-a-listview-with-more-than-one-textview - but honestly just use recyclerview instead and even better use `firebaseui` that binds your data with firebase

Comment: @PeterHaddad when i removed the test key and value from firebase which was set to `article` (key) the app intents to main screen but when i add the key and value back it works fine (but shows single output). Do you have Discord or Twitter so I can send pictures of my database?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Should I use arraylist?

Comment: @ItsBenny_ really just use firebaseui https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md it is so much easier just read the readme and even copy paste it

Comment: Can't figure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I found the answer.
For a database structure like this

```
db-name:
    category:
        unique_id_very_random: value
```

what I did is

```java
ArrayList<String> collectValues = new ArrayList<>();
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot) {
    collectValues.add(ds.getValue(String.class));
}
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YOURACTIVITYJAVAFILENAME.this, R.layout.value_each, R.id.valuePerTxtValue, collectValues); // change YOURACTIVITYJAVAFILENAME to your java file name of the screen where you are showing the list and create a layout and put a textvalue inside the layout (basically its like how you want each items to look like, i think) and change 'R.layout.value_each' to 'R.layout.the_new_layout_name' and 'R.id.valuePerTxtValue' to the new text values name like 'R.id.text_value_name'
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```